# Do I get charged for streaming video from s3 bucket in my website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If I store the big mp4 file in S3 bucket, get the endpoint URL and play that video on my website, do i need to pay the money for this? So do AWS only charge for upload and download from S3 bucket OR it also charge for streaming that content using the endpoint URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will pay the transfer fee from your S3 bucket.

Pricing is here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/.

If you’re trying to cut costs, add a CloudFront distribution in front and add caching.

Comment: Please see my below question too :)

Comment: Hi can’t see another question :(. It does charge for upload and download of that’s your question. Downloads will be reduced using CloudFront and caching

Comment: I've seen S3 price calculator, I'm bit confused. suppose if I have 50 GB of data and my website has 100 users and they have seen all content. So my outbound data transfer will be 50 * 100 = 5000 GB. So total cost would be 5000 * 0.1093 per GB = 546.39 usd per month. is this correct? This is the question. @Ersoy answered it :)

Comment: Yes that’s correct minus the free 1gb you get each month. This depends on your region of the s3 bucket over cost

Comment: If I use cloudfront, won't I pay the extra price for using cloudfront? How does it cut my cost? How much?

Comment: 420 usd according to quick calculator https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#s=CloudFront&key=files/calc-7d2a7a7a4c189f27d4244f32347af707ce5a339d&v=ver20200501p5

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But that's a lot. I think I need to take other solutions such as digitalocean spaces or azure. AWS is looking costly :p

Answer (score 2):

Streaming from a website endpoint is the same as downloading bytes from the S3 bucket. So the answer is yes, you will be charged for data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) can be charged in;

- Storage
- Requests and data retrievals
- Data transfer
- Management and replication

You will be charged for `storage` for saving your video, `data transfer` for streaming, and while making `request`(get, post, put etc).

Comment: I've seen S3 price calculator, I'm bit confused. suppose if I have 50 GB of data and my website has 100 users and they have seen all content. So my outbound data transfer will be 50 * 100 = 5000 GB. So total cost would be 5000 * 0.1093 per GB = 546.39 usd per month. is this correct?

Comment: Up to 1 GB / Month is for free, Next 9.999 TB / Month is $0.09 per gb. it will be around $450.  @MayurAitavadekar